# Neo4j gem - Create relationship between two nodes only if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, relationship, neo4j.rb

If I have two nodes (`self`) and `friend_node`, what's the most efficient way to do this check if I already know my two nodes.

I built this off of what you taught me last time but this seems convoluted given that I know where my nodes are. Is there anything easier?

`self.query_as(:user).match(friend: {uuid: friend_node.id}).where("NOT(user-[:friends_with]->(friend:User))").pluck(:friend) unless friend_node.blank?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's an association on user called `friends`, just do `user.friends.include?(friend_node)`.

Comment: and... i totally should've known this lol. see next question for something done i did -_-